# Trouble with float on C

Tags: c, floating-point, square-root

I have this little program in C that calculates the square root `x` of a positive integer `N` using a recursive function (implemented using a while loop). If I calculate `x` using this:

```
x = (1/2)*(x + N/x) //x0 = 1.0
```

Then `x` keeps growing to inf and then nan. However if I use this:

```
x = (x + N/x)/2 //x0 = 1.0
```

It works fine, why? Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

`1/2` does integer division, its result is `0`, change either or both operand to `double`, e.g:

```
1.0/2
```

Comment: That was insanely fast, thank you!

Comment: Though simply writing `.5` is faster...